# Why does this shiny app work on ShinyApps.io but not Shiny Server?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny app that works locally and also on ShinyApps.io, but it does not work on my Amazon EC2 instance where I have setup Shiny Server. It loads, but I receive Javascript errors.

One error I receive is:

```
navigator.getUserMedia is not a function
```

but I had code to deal with this, which is due to navigator.getUserMedia being deprecated. And another that didn't appear before:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $id.tooltip is not a function
```

My question is if there a general reason why my app would work on ShinyApps.io and locally, but not on my deployment to EC2 / Shiny-Server. Do I need to change some settings on AWS? If there is not a general reason why this may not work, then I can investigate the specific errors, but it does not make sense to me that it works fine in at least two other environments.